# Split pack of text files into multiple subsets according to the content of the files

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I have lot of PDF, DOC[X], TIFF and others files (scans from a shared folder). Each file converted into pack of text files: one text file per page.

Each pack of files could contain multiple documents (for example thee contracts). Document kind could be *not only contract*.

During the processing the pack of the files I don't know what kind of the documents current pack contains and it's possible that one pack contains multiple document kinds (contracts, invoices, etc).

I'm looking for some possible approaches to solve this programmatically.

I'm tried to search something like that but without any success.

**UPD:** I tried to create binary classificator with `scikit-learn` and now looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution was to create binary classifier ([SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)) and train it on classes `first-page` and `not-first-page`. Each item from the dataset was trimmed to 100 tokens (words)

Answer (score 0):

This at its basis, being they are "scans" sounds more like something that could be approached with computer vision, however this is currently far far above my current level of programming.

E.g. projects like SimpleCV may be a good starting point, 
http://www.simplecv.org/

Or possibly you could get away with OCR reading the "scans" and working based on the contents. pytesseract seems popular for this type of task, 
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

However that still lacks defining how you would tell your program that this part of the image means that this is 3 separate contracts, Is there anything about these files in particular that make this clear, e.g. "1 of 3" on the pages,, a logo or otherwise? that will be the main part that determines how complex a problem you are trying to solve.